# consuming C dlls with Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, dll, freepascal, lazarus

I have a Dll function with this signature:

```c
UInt32 Authenticate(uint8 *Key);
```

I'm doing this on Delphi:

```pascal
function Authenticate(Key:string) : UInt32; external 'mylib.dll' name 'Authenticate';
```

But always, the function return 10 (error code) and the application brakes :\

There is a way to do this right?

**UPDATE:** *thanks guys! you're the best!*

Comment: of course uint8 is not equivalent to a string... what is supposed you have to pass as a key to the function, just a pointer to byte?

Comment: @jachguate uint8* is equivalent to PAnsiChar though, in this case

Comment: @David, equivalent is ambiguous in this case XD.  IMHO uint8 is only equivalent to a PByte.   the function expecting a PAnsiChar trough a uint8 pointer is not matter of equivalence but of preference in the c side. One that I don't clearly agree with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

1) `uint8` is the equivilent of `Byte` in Delphi, not `String`.

2) the C code is using the compiler's default calling convention, which is usually `__cdecl`.  Delphi's default calling convention, on the other hand, is `register` instead.  They are not compatible with each other.  If you mismatch the calling convention, the stack and CPU registers will not be managed correctly during the function call at runtime.

A literal translation of the C code would be this instead:

```
function Authenticate(Key: PByte) : UInt32; cdecl; external 'mylib.dll';
```

However, assuming the function is actually expecting a null-terminated string then do this instead:

```
// the function is expecting a pointer to 8-bit data,
// so DO NOT use `PChar`, which is 16-bit in Delphi 2009+...
function Authenticate(Key: PAnsiChar) : UInt32; cdecl; external 'mylib.dll';
```

I would stick with the first declaration, as it matches the original C code.  Even if the function is expecting a null-terminated string as input, you can still pass it in using `PByte` via a type-cast:

```
var
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  Authenticate(PByte(PAnsiChar(S)));
end;
```

Or, if the function allows NULL input for empty strings:

```
var
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  Authenticate(PByte(Pointer(S)));
end;
```

Comment: Definitely a good start.  It's worth noting that Delphi used 8-bit ASCII for versions lower than Delphi 2008, in which case PChar would be preferred.  Here's an excellent link on Delphi string handling and compatibility with Windows: http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa071800a.htm.

Comment: `PAnsiChar` is still preferred over `PChar`, even in pre-2009 versions of Delphi. It makes the code more explicit that it is expecting 8-bit character data, and you don't have to remember to change it from `PChar` to `PAnsiChar` (in order to maintain compatibility with the C code) if the project is upgraded to a 2009+ version of Delphi later on.

Answer (score 2):

I would add nothing to the great Remy's answer, but I would like to give a list of the tools that can help in conversion of C DLL headers to Pascal (in no special order):

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/c2pas
- http://www.astonshell.com/freeware/c2pas32
- http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26951
- http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html
- http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm
- http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/H2Pas
- http://wiki.freepascal.org/Chelper

Beware that these converters can only convert 60-80% of the code, so manual work follows.

The biggest time saver tip I can give is to try to find Visual Basic header translation if it exists for your DLL, and use Marco Cantu's VB converter at http://www.marcocantu.com/tools/vb2delphi.htm. This will probably give you almost 100% automatic conversion (if you are converting just DLL headers, of course). There is also a commercial VBTO converter but trial demo is quite enough for conversion of VB DLL headers to Pascal. Download it here: http://www.vbto.net

Other tips for conversion from C--/C++:

- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html
- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html
- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html
- http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html
- http://www.awitness.org/delphi_pascal_tutorial/c++_delphi

Slightly off topic, but I thought this might be useful to someone...

Answer (score 0):

For starters, change "string" to "pchar".

There might be other problems besides that.

Comment: Use `PAnsiChar` instead if using Delphi 2009+.

Comment: `PByteArray` would be more exact variable type.

Comment: This isn't an answer. There are many more problems, and `PChar` is wrong anyway, as `PChar` isn't a replacement for `pointer to 8-byte unsigned integer` (neither is `string`, of course). It should at best be a comment to the original question; it's certainly not an answer.

Comment: @Ken - uint8 is 8 bits, not bytes, i.e. Byte. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230388%28v=prot.10%29.aspx

Comment: @Gerry: Of course it is. Typo on my part, not reading well enough what I was writing. Thanks for the correction - don't need the link, but I appreciate the effort to provide it. Thanks again. :-)