# C dll header on Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, dll

I want to loadd a function from "x.dll",and I have this definition of the function(.h file):

```
uint32 BioAPI_ModuleAttach(
    const BioAPI_UUID *ModuleGuid,
    const BioAPI_VERSION *Version,
    const BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS *MemoryFuncs,
    uint32 DeviceID,
    uint32 Reserved1,
    uint32 Reserved2,
    uint32 Reserved3,
    BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR *FunctionTable,
    uint32 NumFunctionTable,
    const void *Reserved4,
    BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR NewModuleHandle);

typedef uint32 BioAPI_HANDLE, *BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR;
```

But, I only to pass the last parameter and the others I want to pass `0` (null)... How can I implement? There is any way to do automatic with de .lib?

I tried, but I implemented in wrong way.. :\

```
function BioAPI_ModuleAttach(
           ModuleGuid: array of Byte; 
           Version: HWND; 
           MemoryFuncs: HWND; 
           DeviceID: UInt32; 
           Reserved1: UInt32; 
           Reserved2: UInt32; 
           Reserved3: UInt32; 
           FunctionTable: HWND; 
           NumFunctionTable: UInt32; 
           Reserved4: Pointer; 
           NewModuleHandle: PINT) : UInt32; cdecl; external 'PvFw.dll';
```

Thanks, for attention.

Comment: I edited your question to format the code as a code block, but it's not clear to me yet what you're asking. Perhaps you could edit it to make your question clearer?

Comment: Are you having trouble converting the C code to Delphi?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `cdecl` with a DLL?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to import functions from a Dll...

Comment: cdcel, was the only way to make this function works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787669/consuming-c-dlls-with-delphi

Comment: Using `array of Byte` for a pointer argument is wrong; try `PGUID` instead

Comment: as far as I know, everything starting with a star is a pointer, you can pass "NIL" for last parameter and you can replace UInt32 with Cardinal

Comment: automatical conversions were made, you may Google for them.
For exaple JEDI API Library should have used some. But you should always check results of auto conversion manually later. Those tools might get behind most recent C or Delphi version. But you can google for them and give them a try.

Comment: For the record, the tools hopefully still maintaining: http://freepascal.org/tools/h2pas.var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sources, I would convert that like this:

```
const
  BioAPI_MAX_STR_LEN = 255;

type
  BioAPI_RETURN = UInt32;

  BioAPI_VERSION_PTR = ^BioAPI_VERSION;
  BioAPI_VERSION = record
    Major: UInt32;
    Minor: UInt32;
  end;

  BioAPI_MALLOC = function(
    Size: UInt32;
    AllocRef: Pointer;
    FileName: PAnsiChar;
    Line: UInt32; 
  ): Pointer stdcall;

  // etc...

  BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS_PTR = ^BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS;
  BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS = record
    Malloc_func: BioAPI_MALLOC;
    Free_func: BioAPI_FREE;
    Realloc_func: BioAPI_REALLOC;
    Calloc_func: BioAPI_CALLOC;
    AllocRef: Pointer;
  end;

  BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR_PTR = ^BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR;
  BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR = record
    Name: array[0..BioAPI_MAX_STR_LEN - 1] of AnsiChar;
    Address: BioAPI_PROC_ADDR;
  end;

  // etc... I'll leave the rest for you. ;-)

function BioAPI_ModuleAttach(
  ModuleGuid: PGUID;
  Version: BioAPI_VERSION_PTR;
  MemoryFuncs: BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS_PTR;
  DeviceID,
  Reserved1,
  Reserved2,
  Reserved3: UInt32;
  FunctionTable: BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR_PTR;
  NumFunctionTable: UInt32;
  Reserved4: Pointer;
  var NewModuleHandle: HMODULE): BioAPI_RETURN; stdcall;
```

Note that in Win32, `BioAPI` is #defined as `__stdcall`, so `cdecl` is definitely wrong. There is nothing that indicates that records must be packed. I would leave them at their natural alignment.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could work:

```
function BioAPI_ModuleAttach(
  ModuleGuid: PByte; // pass a pointer to the first array element
  Version: PByte;    // PByte probably is wrong here, look up the type!
  MemoryFuncs: PByte; // Also probably wrong, what is BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS?
  DeviceID: UInt32; 
  Reserved1: UInt32; 
  Reserved2: UInt32; 
  Reserved3: UInt32; 
  FunctionTable: PBYTE; // pass a pointer to a BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR 
  NumFunctionTable: UInt32; // that's probably the length of the above
  Reserved4: Pointer; 
  NewModuleHandle: PUINT32) : UInt32; cdecl; external 'PvFw.dll';
```

Calling it like this should work, if all the parameters can be zero or NULL:

```
var
  DeviceId: UInt32; // LongWord
  Handle: UInt32; // LongWord;
begin
  DeviceId := <something>
  Handle := 0;
  Res := BioAPI_ModuleAttach(nil, nil, nil, DeviceId, 0, 0, 0, nil, 0, nil, @Handle);
```

Of course this assumes a lot, since you did not provide any information about many of the pointer parameters. I have declared them as PByte, but that's probably wrong.

Comment: If you know nothing about the pointer params then you may be better declaring them as Pointer. The last param looks like pointer to HMODULE. I'd probably do it as var NewModuleHandle: HMODULE

Answer (score 1):

```
const
  BioAPI_MAX_STR_LEN = 255;
  BioAPI_OK = 0;
  BioAPI_INVALID_HANDLE = 0;

type
  BioAPI_UUID = packed array[0..15] of Byte; // or TGUID
  BioAPI_UUID_PTR = ^BioAPI_UUID;

  BioAPI_DEVICE_ID = UInt32;

  BioAPI_VERSION = record
        Major: UInt32;
        Minor: UInt32;
  end;
  BioAPI_VERSION_PTR = ^BioAPI_VERSION;

    BioAPI_MALLOC = function(Size: UInt32; Allocref: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
  BioAPI_FREE = procedure(Memblock: Pointer; Allocref: Pointer); cdecl;
    BioAPI_REALLOC = function(Memblock: Pointer; Size: UInt32; Allocref: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;
    BioAPI_CALLOC = function(Num: UInt32; Size: UInt32; Allocref: Pointer): Pointer; cdecl;

  BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS = record
        Malloc_func: BioAPI_MALLOC;
    Free_func: BioAPI_FREE;
        Realloc_func: BioAPI_REALLOC;
        Calloc_func: BioAPI_CALLOC;
        AllocRef: Pointer;
  end;
  BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS_PTR = ^BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS;

  BioAPI_PROC_ADDR = function: UInt32; stdcall;

  BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ = record
        Name: packed array[0..BioAPI_MAX_STR_LEN-1] of AnsiChar;
        Address: BioAPI_PROC_ADDR;
  end;
  BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR = array[0..0] of BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_;
  BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR_PTR = ^BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR;

  BioAPI_HANDLE = UInt32;
  BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR = ^BioAPI_HANDLE;

function BioAPI_ModuleAttach(
    ModuleGuid: BioAPI_UUID_PTR;
    Version: BioAPI_VERSION_PTR;
    MemoryFuncs: BioAPI_MEMORY_FUNCS_PTR;
    DeviceID: BioAPI_DEVICE_ID;
    Reserved1: UInt32;
    Reserved2: UInt32;
    Reserved3: UInt32;
    FunctionTable: BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ADDR_PTR;
    NumFunctionTable: UInt32;
    Reserved4: Pointer;
    var NewModuleHandle: BioAPI_HANDLE): UInt32; cdecl; external 'PvFw.dll';

procedure Test;
var
  NewModuleHandle: BioAPI_HANDLE;
begin
  if BioAPI_ModuleAttach(nil, nil, nil, 0, 0, 0, 0, nil, 0, nil, NewModuleHandle) = BioAPI_OK then
  begin
    if NewModuleHandle <> BioAPI_INVALID_HANDLE then
    begin
      // Success
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In case **cdecl** is not the correct convention replace with **stdcall**

Comment: What's your source for all this? How can you tell that the records are packed?

Comment: Source: BioAPI Specification. About packed records, you can only tell if you debug the implementation, I believe though only BioAPI_FUNC_NAME_ will have issues if the structure is not byte alignment.

Comment: Surely if the structs were packed, that would be made clear in the header file? It would be exceptionally unusual for a C or C++ library to pack structs. So, you'd be better off assuming that they were not packed.

Comment: @David: http://www.koders.com/c/fidCCB5029ADB3BCBD58E568E8A7096D44CF8BDD53D.aspx?s=Enroll#L407